# Read Contact for xConnect pipeline returns "No entities were read from xConnect"

Tags: xdb, xconnect, data-exchange-framework, salesforce-connect

I installed Sitecore Connect for Salesforce 2.0.1 and I set up environment using manual for 2.0.1.

However, after starting Pipeline Batch "xConnect Contacts to Salesforce Sync" I get info message that no entities were read from xConnect although I created few contacts in database using xConnect API:

*`INFO [Data Exchange] No entities were read from xConnect. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect, pipeline step: Read Contacts from xConnect, pipeline step identifier: ef308355-94e3-444c-9f8f-164fe26f3f8a`*

I checked xDB database and I saw created contacts. After debugging suspicious class I found that xdbContext.Contacts.GetBatchEnumerator() returns TotalCount property 0 which is probably the cause of "No entities..." message.

Any clue why this happens?

Comment: If you go to Experience Profile, can you see the same contacts?

Comment: Also check if contacts are indexed. If there  are only anonymous contacts you should set settings to allow indexing them if you need those contacts.

Comment: I would bet that the problem is that there are no interations for those users. As you are creating users programatically through xConnect API, try to trigger a goal after your current code. Mark Goal as "IsLiveEvent" to make processing of goal immediate. Follow this documentation to trigger goal -> https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/interactions/add-events.html#adding-a-goal-to-an-interaction

Comment: @Peter I can't see contacts in Experience Profile.

Comment: @DionisTakac I thought so. Please follow my last advice and trigger a goal or do som interaction with those contacts. This will show contacts in Experience Profile + enable them for sync. I will create answer when it's working with more details

Comment: @PeterProchazka I added goal as you said following instructions, but I don't see any difference. Experience Profile is still empty and I still get message "No entities were read from xConnect" after triggering pipeline.

Comment: Have you configured it as "IsLiveEvent"? Have you deployed goal? That is really strange if it's not working

Comment: I did as you said. I added "IsLiveEvent" and deployed the goal, but still my Experience Profile is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When querying for the contacts, the search usually goes through the xConnect Search role to search the xDB Index. If you are not getting results, you might want to check to make sure that your contacts are in the index.

## Checking Contacts

To check if contacts are in the index, you should visit your Solr web admin portal. From there, you would run a query.

The URL will be something like:

`https://127.0.0.1:8961/solr/#/sc9_xdb/query`

... where [127.0.0.1:8961] is the URL and port for accessing your Sorl instance and [sc9_xdb] is the name of your xDB Index Core.

## Possible issues

If contacts are not in the index, this could be one of several issues:

1. Your contacts are anonymous and not being indexed. You can update configuration to index anonymous contacts (for testing purposes) or you can identify your contacts.
2. The search indexing service is not running, or throwing errors, and not updating your index. Check the Search Indexer logs.
3. Something might be up with your Solr instance, but this is less likely.

Comment: I would also add default Contact Filter. Probably there are no result by filter.

Comment: I already updated configuration to index anonymous contacts. Can you tell me how can I exactly verify that contacts are in the index?

Comment: I have added details around checking index. Essentially, you need to access your Solr web portal and look at the documents

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I checked Solr, my xdb database is empty. Can you tell me where is located Search Indexer log? I checked Search.log inside sc9/App_Data/logs and I haven't found any error, just infos and warnings.

Comment: The search indexer is installed as a separate worker process. Typically, in an XP0, you will find this on your system inside the xConnect installation root.

Your path probably looks something like: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc9.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker

Comment: I tried to open log file but  it was too large so I deleted it. Now I don't have any new log file. I noticed that I don't have "Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - [instance name].xconnect-IndexWorker" among services. For other instance for example I have this services but I can't start.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue. I had to install everything from the beginning and make sure that "Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer" is running since that was the main problem in my case. @JayS thank you for help.